# FAB button go behind admob ads in android 4.0+

Tags: android

I am trying to place fab button above adview but in android 4.0+ fab button go's behind even if i define `layout_above="@+id/ad_view"`

Here is my code in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:background="#FFFAFAFA"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
                </FrameLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />


            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/ad_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:adSize="FULL_WIDTHx50"
                app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#fF312B35"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:itemIconTint="#f3ae1b"
            app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/White"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
            app:theme="@style/DrawerStyle" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any idea?

Comment: i think `android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"` was work on `RelativeLayout` only, CMIIW

Comment: Can i wrap fab in relativelayout?

Comment: I think so, but you must wrap both fab and AdView, then you can use `android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"`, I haven't try it my self, but i think it was do able

Comment: If i wrap fab in RelativeLayout both fab and adview not showing.

Comment: how you wrap it on RelativeLayout?

Comment: <RelativeLayout    android:layout_width="wrap_content"    android:layout_gravity="bottom"    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   FAB >>>> ADVIEW      </RelativeLayout>

Comment: i try your code and do like on https://pastebin.com/TDdyxPSh, and it working

Comment: Thank you so much its solved.

Comment: glad i can help, I'll write this as answer for future reference, in case some people have the same problem :D

Comment: Sorry i am new here please tell me how can i close this ques?

Comment: you mean delete or accept the answer? if you want the question still on stackoverflow, and only close it, just accept my answer below, in progress of writing at the moment :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative layout inflates the Views in the order you have declared it. To know more you can use [Systrace](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace.html).  It will display how the views are rendered. Replace your code by below and let me know by accepting the answer if it helps. Thanks

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:adSize="FULL_WIDTHx50"
            app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```